# Error in building cordova app. What to do?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, visual-studio-cordova

I am having an error "Cannot find module 'q'" as I build my BlankCordovaApp project. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

sorry I cant post a picture cause I am new here. Here's what i got after building the project:

```
1> Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3, Configuration: Debug Android 
1> GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\index.‌​js;scripts\platformOverrides.js 
1> C:\..\..\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3
 > call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm. 
1> MDAVSCLI : error :Cannot find module 'q'
Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped
```

Comment: I think more details may be necessary to solve your problem. What is the code that is prompting that error?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

This problem is indicative of a problem with `node.js`.

Usually, these can be solved by simply going to BUILD/REBUILD SOLUTION in the top menu of Visual Studio.  If that doesn't work, continue with **Solution 2** or **Solution 3**

## Solution 2

Navigate to your `bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\` folder and verify that the `q` folder exists and has content.  There should be several folders there that resemble the contents of a Git project.  At the very minimum, there should be a `package.json` file.

1. You should backup your `q` folder by renaming it to `q_old` or something similar.   You can find the `node_modules` folder at `bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\`.
2. Add a new folder called `q`.
3. Copy the `package.json` file from `q_old` into your new `q` folder
4. From the new `q` folder, execute `npm install` from the CLI (command line interface).

Be aware that this requires a `package.json` folder, which should be present in your `bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\` folder.

## Solution 3

Try the Node add-on `npm-install-missing`.  From your CLI, type

`npm-install -g npm-install-missing`

After that has finished installing, you can simply type `npm-install-missing` from your project directory, which should look something like this:

`C:\Users\<MYUSERNAME>\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\> npm-install-missing`

Once you've got something in cmd that looks like that, press Enter and you should see something very similar to what occurred when you installed the Node Module `node-install-missing`.

Comment: I found some `package.json` in `npm-cache` has a `NULL`. Is this also the cause of the error?

Comment: @RehmardR.Butad – Just means that the last time the package was read, it read the `package.json` as null.

Comment: I think I am having a problem in my previous installation of the cordova tools for visual studio community edition. I re-installed my application and the problem now is fixed..